Chrome: text being selected on resize
Our project has a custom (web) component that supports moving and resizing of 'windows' on a dashboard canvas. You can grab a window edge to resize it, and there's also a widget that lets you change the size of the 'canvas' on which the windows exist, by dragging it up or down.
This code has existed for several years, but starting around 1 week ago, a number of users have reported that, when doing actions involving dragging, all of the text in the dashboard area gets selected, and the application doesn't respond to the drag as it should. You can click outside of the dashboard area to clear the selection, but it's an annoying behavior.
I assume that a new browser version is behind the change in behavior; I first noticed after Chrome version 125.0.6422.113 was applied. (The problem can also be reproduced in Edge; uncertain about other browsers.)
I realize this question is vague in details (as there's a decent amount of code involved which I'm not at liberty to share in toto, and I'm not sure what would be relevant), but:

Anybody aware of a recent change in Chrome behavior in this area?
Any specific APIs I should be paying attention to, when looking for something our code might be doing wrong? The Selection API seems like an obvious one, but I don't see that being used.

Setting a CSS rule of user-select: none; on the top-level element of the dashboard does avoid the issue, but it feels more like a workaround than a fix.

It's possible that it should've been behaving this way and a bug was fixed which finally caused it to happen. And user-select: none isn't actually a workaround if the text should not be selectable but is. You could try moving the drag handler to an element that's earlier in the HTML and only firing when it's targeting the handle used for resizing, but of course that may just be asking for more issues to fix.
